# How to make a div overlap another while hovered

Tags: html, css, hover, visibility

I wanted to make a div that contains some info about a product and when the user hovered the product that div that contains information pops up but the info div seems to be glitching somehow and isn't stable

Here's the code:

```css
.product {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.product:hover + .info {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

How can I have a stable version that doesn't glitch and appear and disappear every millisecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because your mouse is hovering `.info` instead of `.product`. You need to add `.info:hover`

```css
.product {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.product:hover + .info, .info:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```